# Accessing file attributes with std::filesystem::directory_entry

Tags: c++, attributes, c++20

I'm using Microsoft's implementation of the C++ Standard Library to search through an NTFS directory. I need to know if any given file has the hidden attribute set, which Win32 API encodes in a bitfield ([`attributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-attribute-constants)), but I don't see a way to access that information using `std::filesystem::directory_entry`.

Microsoft's implementation reads in these attributes. I can see them in `std::filesystem::directory_entry._Cached_data._Attributes`. I understand this is Windows specific, but cppreference for `std::filesystem::file_status` suggests I should be able to access them:

> Many low-level OS APIs for directory traversal retrieve file attributes along with the next directory entry. The constructors and
> the non-const member functions of std::filesystem::directory_iterator store these attributes, if any, in the pointed-to std::filesystem::directory_entry without calling directory_entry::refresh, which makes it possible to examine the attributes of the directory entries as they are being iterated over, without making additional system calls.

[source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_entry/status)

Must I access the filesystem a second time just to read in that attribute myself? Or is there some secret way to do this I haven't discovered yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *standard* way to access the cached attributes, and the standard `<filesystem>` library has no concept of a "hidden" attribute.

Looking at [Microsoft's implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/filesystem) of `directory_entry`, I do see it has a non-standard method named `_Has_cached_attribute()` for testing the bits of the `_Cached_data._Attributes` field:

```
_NODISCARD bool _Has_cached_attribute(const __std_fs_file_attr _Attrs) const noexcept {
    return _Bitmask_includes_any(_Cached_data._Attributes, _Attrs);
}
```

However, this method is `private`, so you can't *directly* use it yourself. And I don't see any other methods for accessing the `_Cache_data` the way you want.

So yes, you *should* access the filesystem a second time to read the attributes yourself.

But, that being said, it is possible to *indirectly* access a `private` method using some template trickery:

http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2010/07/access-to-private-members-thats-easy.html

http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2011/12/access-to-private-members-safer.html

Comment: Thank you Remy. Seems silly to have to read this in a second time, but that is what I suspected.